# Limiting Behaviour of Root Mean Square Normal Random Variables - Related to Chi-Squared Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

[image: Exercise 2.9]

Above is my question. I have done the first part - made hard work of it, albeit, but still, it's done.

The next part is where I am stuck. Intuitively, it seems (to me!) like we should have $R_n \simeq S_n$, where
$$S_n = X_1 + \dots = X_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j.$$
Unfortunately, this isn't the case: if it were, then we'd have "$\to Z \sim N(0,1)$", not "$\to 1$". (?) Also, I have, of course, noted that if we define $X^{(n)} = (X_1,...,X_n)$, then we have the scenario of (i), and $R_n = \Vert X^{(n)} \Vert$; whether this turns out to be of help is another matter!

Any advice **for part (ii) only** would be most appreciated. I would like to think that determining how to do (ii) would then make me able to do (iii) - I can live in hope. :)

Best regards, Sam

---

PS: This is the last question on the last example sheet for a pretty tough course (for 3rd year undergrad), so I expect the answer won't be massively simple. Alternatively, it could be really simple *if* you can get it. =D

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (ii): Show that $R_n^2/n\to1$ almost surely; no approximations or additional constructions necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I did think of that. But the theorems are all in terms of
$$S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$$
... and of course all we need for the $X_i$ is that they're independent. Squaring them certainly keeps the independence. Come on Sam! =P

Comment: With a bit of luck $\Bbb E[X^2] = 1$ for $X \sim N(0,1)$. And yes, it does, since it's the variance (zero mean). So the strong law of large numbers gives this pretty much trivially. That's what you get for doing maths at ~10.20pm!

Comment: Done now. =P How easy it is to make a mess of things when you think they're going to be difficult! This is a one line proof, or two if you want to embellish it a bit!